# line up divs using css and HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to line up 4 `divs` inline using CSS and also make them responsive.

I tried this css

```
.col {
  border:1px solid black;
  width:20%;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;
  text-align:left;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .col {
    width:40%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .col {
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

But as the screen gets smaller, they are slightly different sizes

I created a fiddle of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/j2de3tt8/

I am trying to make it like: http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/Divi/shop-no-sidebar/

Comment: Did you write the media queries yourself and do you understand plainly their effect ?

Comment: So inspect the element on the live page, and you'll get your styles.

Comment: @Vucko i would love to do that but i dont think its quite that easy!

Comment: I don't see `.col` divs having different sizes, but they are not aligned properly when the screen width is in 500-800 px range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a modification to Abhitalks' fiddle. I've removed the padding:0; and margin:0; from everything, as I don't see this as necessary. If you're setting your container div to 100% width, all your other dimension and margin units need to be %'s as well.

the key is to subtract 2% from the width of your .col's to allow for the margin that will 'touch' the padding of your container div.

```
.col {
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 23%; display: inline-block;
   padding: 2%; margin: 1%;
   text-align: left; 
   font-size: 16px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Zemo/482smdfq/

You may need a media query when the .col's get very small on a narrow screen.

Answer (score 2):

> But as the screen gets smaller, they are slightly different sizes

Two things.

1. Compute the total width occupied by your `div`s carefully. Especially, with margins and all. To be safe, it is better to define your `box-sizing` so that you know and are in control of the widths.

Adding this to your CSS...

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

... will help keep a standard `box-sizing` and act as a very minimal and simple normalize/reset CSS for you. With this, now you know that the `margin`s will not be included while calculating the widths. So, you need to subtract your `margin`s from the total width of the container to arrive at the optimal size of your child `div`s.

For example:

```
.cont { width: 100%; } /* total width of parent */
.col {
  margin: 1%; /* margin of 1% means a total of 2% left-and-right margins */
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .col { width: 98%; } /* reduce 2% from the total width */
}
```

2. You have your child `div`s set to `display: inline-block`. Now, you need to be careful with that because `inline-block` take into account the white-spaces as well. So, in your case the breaks in your HTML are causing the extra spacing between the `div`s and it seems to you that the sizes are getting different. This is more pronounced as you change the screen size.

There are a couple of ways to get rid of that, but specifically in your case the zero font-size trick will work. Keep the `font-size` on your parent as `0` to collapse the white-spaces:

```
.cont { font-size: 0px; }
```

And, reset the `font-size` on your child `div`s back again:

```
.col { font-size: 16px; }
```

Combining both together you get:

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/v69gadou/**

**Snippet:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.cont {
  width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; 
  text-align: center; font-size: 0px; 
}
.col {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20%; display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px; margin: 1%;
  text-align: left; 
  font-size: 16px; 
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .col {
    width: 40%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .col {
    width: 98%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
 <div class="col">col</div>
 <div class="col">col</div>
 <div class="col">col</div>
 <div class="col">col</div>
 <div class="col">col</div>
 <div class="col">col</div>
 <div class="col">col</div>
 <div class="col">col</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that looks better, is there a way i can make the four display to the edge of the .cont container?

Comment: @charlie: That is even easier. You don't need `inline-block` and other tricks to tame them. Just `float` the `div`s and that's it. See -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/8ojcwp34/

Comment: essentially, i want four inline at 25% each with margins, whats the best way to do this?

Comment: will i need to set the margins at 1% then the width at 21% (1% off the width for each)

Comment: @charlie: It seems you are wanting to get this kind of layout -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/jmLzd95x/ -- Are you?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .col {
    width:80%;
  }
}
```

Hope this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

why not try [columns](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp) ?

here's how:

```css
.cont {

  width: 100%;

  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;

  border: 1px solid black;

  text-align: center;

  -webkit-column-count: 4;

  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

  -moz-column-count: 4;

  /* Firefox */

  column-count: 4;

}

.col {

  border: 1px solid black;

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {

  .cont {

    -webkit-column-count: 2;

    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

    -moz-column-count: 2;

    /* Firefox */

    column-count: 2;

  }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

  .cont {

    -webkit-column-count: 1;

    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

    -moz-column-count: 1;

    /* Firefox */

    column-count: 1;

  }

}
```

```html
<div class="cont">

  <div class="col">col</div>
  <div class="col">col</div>
  <div class="col">col</div>
  <div class="col">col</div>

  <div class="col">col</div>
  <div class="col">col</div>
  <div class="col">col</div>
  <div class="col">col</div>

</div>
```